# Blazor server side HeadOutlet issues

Tags: blazor-server-side, json-ld

I use HeadOutlet to have some components write metadata on the head section of my Server side app pages, but I am facing two issues:

1. Trying to place json-ld Structured Data for SEO purposes on the
   HeadOutlet throws an exception saying *scripts should not be placed
   inside components*

```html
    <HeadContent>
        <script type="application/ld+json">
            {
            "@@context": "https://schema.org/",
            "@@type": "Product",
            "name": "@productName"
            }
        </script>
    </HeadContent>
```

2. Some of the metadata values are not available until OnAfterRender
   event is triggered, but HeadOutlet does not seem to refresh when a
   component updates its contents.

```html
<HeadContent>
    <meta name="description" content="@productDescription">
</HeadContent>

@code {

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            description = GetDescription();
                StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```